# How should I version control (with SVN, for instance) a crontab?

Tags: cron

I would like to version control my server's configuration, in case something happens to my server.

I think crontab files themselves are not intended to be edited directly (only through crontab commands), so how would I go about versioning them? Should I version the files anyway? Is there something else I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're trying to automate something on a web application. It clearly goes beyond the simple fact of your server crashing. What if you want to add another front-end server for example ?

People in the ruby community came out with a pretty nice tool, "whenever" (https://github.com/javan/whenever) to solve this issue.

Namely, the proper way is *not* to version control the crontab. It's rather up to each app to be able to properly configure itself.

In the case of Rails applications for example, you would use a tool like Capistrano to automate your deployment. And one of the capistrano task would be to setup the correct cron jobs, thanks to whenvever. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll look into PHP application deployment tools then ;)

Comment: Phing looks like it could be the way to go.